# Invariant Subspace on $\mathbf{C}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

> Find all the invariant subspaces of $A$ viewed as a linear map on  $\mathbf{C}^3$
>   when A is
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}5 & 1&-1\\0 & 4&0\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know how to find the invariant subspaces of $A$ when it is on $\mathbf{R}^3$. It is the kernel and the eigenspaces and $\mathbf{R}^3$. But how about $\mathbf{C}^3$?

The characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^3+12\lambda^2-48\lambda+64=-(\lambda-4)^3$. The eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ 
 and$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0&1\end{bmatrix}^T$.
So for $\mathbf{R}^3$, the invariant spaces are its kernel and its eigenspaces (both 1 dimension and 2 dimension), and $\mathbf{R}^3$. For $\mathbf{C}^3$, is it just adding $\mathbf{C}^3$, since I don't have complex roots for the determinant to add?

Comment: It's just the same: evaluate $\;\det(zI-A)\;$, find roots (eigenvalues), then eigenspaces and etc.

Comment: So you mean it is just the roots should be the complex number?

Comment: Well, no: in this case the characteristic polynomial is $\;(x-4)(x-2)^2\;$ , and each eigenvalue has a one-dimensional eigenspace (which, btw, means the matrix isn't diagonalizable)

Comment: If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the eigenspaces of $A$ on $R^3$. then wouldn't $E_n+iE_m$, $n,m \in\{1,2\}$ be the eigenspaces in $C^3$?

Comment: @Cas What? I don't understand what you ask. The eigenspaces of $\;\lambda=2,\,4\;$ are invariant already, and this matrix's kernel is, obviously, trivial...

Comment: The invariant subspace is Ker,Eigen space, and C^2, is it right?

Comment: @Maesumi How to relate to the complex space?

Comment: @Castalia520 You say you know how to do this over $\mathbb R$. Could you include what your answer would be in that case? (actually it's essentially the same over $\mathbb C$).

Answer (score 1):

on $C^3$ you have next problem for $w = u + iv \in C^3$:

$Aw = Au + iAv = \lambda u + i\lambda v$, and actually we need to solve

$Re(Aw) = \lambda u ,$

$Im(Aw) =\lambda v$

but as we saw that $SpA = \{2, 4\}$, then our problem represents like

$Au = \lambda u ,$

$Av =\lambda v$.

Where $v,u \in R^3$. So you have 2 Subspaces: $R^2\times iR^2$ for $\lambda = 2$ and $R\times iR$ for $\lambda = 4$